# SSL issues with puppet agent at openSUSE

Tags: ssl, puppet, opensuse

I have a master running at my vps, and it has a simple helloworld manifest which works fine with any ubuntu machine I have. It connects, exchanges keys and creates test file allright, so I'm sure  it's not server issue.

The agent which is running at a virtual machine with openSUSE says:

```
err: Could not request certificate: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed.  This is often because the time is out of sync on the server or client
```

I believe it's probably a broken or missing lib, since the package is not built very accurately - it wouldn't start out of the box because of wrong path to lockfile, for example. So how do I figure out what exactly is wrong here?

The time is allright, I've checked it.

I probably could do without SSL if it's possible, since that SUSE machines are just for training, but it's the last opportunity.

Comment: root@Ubuntu-1110:~# date --utc
Sat Dec 15 07:26:19 UTC 2012
linux-fjmb:~ # date --utc
Sat Dec 15 07:26:20 UTC 2012

Comment: Have you tested against multiple different puppet masters?

Comment: I set up three, one on local machine, ubuntu, one on vps, ubuntu and one on another virtual machine, opensuse. No avail.

Comment: Right - what I'm getting at is that your OpenSUSE client only trusts the first puppet master that it connected to, which might not be this one.  Try deleting `/var/lib/puppet/ssl` (or whatever your `puppet.conf` uses for `ssldir`) and try again.

Comment: Tried that, would not work.

Comment: Test with `openssl` - let's see what kind of validation error is happening.  `openssl s_client -connect puppet.master.dns.name:8140 -CAfile /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/a1rVsmL0 - 19 self-signed certificate, but I guess that's normal in this case. Have the same on working host.

Comment: So the `ca.pem` file doesn't exist.. has the agent been run since you deleted the `ssl` directory?

Comment: Right, can't find ca.pem, only /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/linux-fjmb.local.pem. The agent had been run.

Comment: What version of ruby are you on?  Also, does your `server` config in `puppet.conf` match exactly to the CN of the certificate (`ubuntu-1110-oneiric-64-minimal`)?

Comment: Name: puppet Version: 2.7.6-4.1.2; ruby --version ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: I have a line in server config: dns_alt_names = cloudcabin.org, puppet.cloudcabin.org, and it's in the server cert: openssl x509 -in /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ubuntu-1110-oneiric-64-minimal.pem -text | grep DNS
DNS:cloudcabin.org, DNS:puppet.cloudcabin.org, DNS:ubuntu-1110-oneiric-64-minimal

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6743/discussion-between-roman-grazhdan-and-shane-madden)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things to check.

First, there's apparently known SSL validation issues when you're running different ruby versions between agents and masters; see [here](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/9084).  Make sure your master is running 1.9.x (I don't think Ubuntu 11.10 would by default).

Second, SSL validation is based around hostnames; your puppet agent is configured to point to a hostname of `puppet`, which the certificate that the puppet master doesn't have as its CN or an alt name - validation should fail.  Change the agent's config to point to one of the names that's in the cert, like `puppet.cloudcabin.org`.

Comment: It's a part of the answer in my case. What worked for me is ruby 1.9 at both client and server and puppet 3 on both client and server. In ubuntu ruby 1.9.1 is in the repos but should be chosen explicitly, the package name is ruby1.9.1, and puppet 3 can be installed from puppetlabs' repo. In suse, ruby 1.9 is default, and the package for puppet 3 can be found here: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/systemsmanagement:/puppet/openSUSE_12.2/ Thanks a lot for your patience.